# SSL Page embedding Non-SSL video from Vimeo

Tags: ssl, video, vimeo-api

I am using an iframe to embed video from Vimeo in our Moodle LMS. My code works perfectly in Chrome, IE and Firefox, but not Safari. I am using the standard Vimeo API to embed the video. I know the issue is SSL related because I can remove the S from HTTP in the url and the embedded video works perfectly. I can't run our LMS in an unsecured environment, and the videos are no threat, but vimeo will not stream their video using ssl because of the overhead. Anyone have a solution that works across all browsers?

Comment: Find/set up an HTTPS proxy, or host the videos on another platform that supports HTTPS for their embed widgets. (Or don’t embed them, but just link to them, maybe in a new tab/popup.)

Answer (score 0):

[Vimeo's Embedding Videos FAQ page](https://vimeo.com/help/faq/sharing-videos/embedding-videos#can-i-embed-my-video-on-an-https-domain) indicates that it does support HTTPS. Are you following these instructions?

> **Can I embed my video on an HTTPS domain?**
>
> > You sure can!
> >
> > Our embed code is now “protocol relative,” which means that we adhere to the protocol of your website, whether it’s HTTP or HTTPS.
> >
> > If you’re using an older version of the Vimeo embed code (with a http://player.vimeo.com URL within it), you’ll simply need to change “http” to “https” and it should start working!

and

> **Why doesn't my video load when I preview it in my website editor?**
>
> > Vimeo's embed code uses protocol-relative URLs, meaning that we automatically match the embedded video's protocol to your website's — either HTTP or HTTPS.
> >
> > If you are previewing your website with a program like Dreamweaver, the video will not load because the program cannot determine the correct protocol to use. That said, the video should work flawlessly once you publish it.
> >
> > There are two ways you can test your embed:
> >     Add http:// to the player.vimeo.com URL in your website's source code. This should allow you to see the embed in preview mode.
> >     Publish a live test page where you can see the embedded video in action.